# Can gradients flow through (Tensorflow) tf.distributions.Normal sample()?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I want to implement a stochastic variant of a model in `TensorFlow`.
I have checked the source code but wanted to confirm that gradients

> **DO** flow through the variable *x*,    where *x = "normal".sample()*.

The reason is that the function **`sample()`** utilizes the reparameterization

> trick *x = mean + sigma * noise (0,1)*

.

Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: Have you tested it? It should be quite straightforward.

Comment: I wanted to test an implementation in tensorflow, but I am a pytorch user. I tried implementing it and testing if gradients do flow and I get none which probably means no, but the documentation and source code of the probability function shows the reparameterised normal sampling. But I am not confident in my tests in tensorflow as I am a pytorch user.